# How to display the present selected value from the database in a dropdown

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, dropdown

I'm currently working on my update function for my project.
I have a dropdown for **groups**. I want to display the current selected value/option of the said dropdown. The value will be retrieved from an SQLite database. The code below displays ONLY the options retrieved from the database, but not the present selected value.

html:

```
      <select name="groups" ng-model="memProfAdd.groups">
                <option ng-repeat="group in memGroups" value="{{group.id}}">
                    {{group.name}}
                </option>
       </select>
```

js:

```
 //DROPDOWN: Member Groups
  var query = "SELECT id, name FROM groups";
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res){
    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
      for (var i=0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
        $scope.memGroups.push(res.rows.item(i));
      }
    }
  }, function(err){
    $cordovaToast.showShortBottom('Something Went Wrong').then(function(success){}, function(err){});
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

Comment: where you want to display the present selected value?

Comment: i want to display it also in the dropdown. For example, the current selected value (retrieved from the database) is Group One, the displayed/selected option is also "Group One"

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to assign some value to the `$scope.memProfAdd.groups` first.

```
 //DROPDOWN: Member Groups
  var query = "SELECT id, name FROM groups";
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res){
    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
      for (var i=0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
        $scope.memGroups.push(res.rows.item(i));
      }
      $scope.memProfAdd.groups = $scope.memGroups[0].id;
    }
  }, function(err){
    $cordovaToast.showShortBottom('Something Went Wrong').then(function(success){}, function(err){});
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

Comment: what will be the next step after that?

Comment: how will i call the value of $scope.memProfAdd.groups = $scope.memGroups[0] in my html code?

Comment: change `$scope.memProfAdd.groups = $scope.memGroups[0];` this line to `$scope.memProfAdd.groups = $scope.memGroups[0].id;` Then it will work. check my updated ans

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

HTML

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
            <span class="input-label">
                <b>Religion</b>
            </span>
            <select name="religions">
                <option selected>{{currentReligion.name}}</option>
                <option ng-repeat="religion in otherReligions" 
                value="{{religion.id}}">
                    {{religion.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </label>
```

JS:

```
//Get selected current religion
  $scope.currentReligion = [];
  var query = "SELECT religions.name FROM members "
  + "INNER JOIN religions ON members.religion_id=religions.id WHERE members.id=?"
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [$scope.memberID]).then(function(res){
   if (res.rows.length > 0) {
      for (var i=0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
        //$scope.religion.push(res.rows.item(i));
        $scope.currentReligion = res.rows.item(0);
      }
    }
  }, function(err){
    $cordovaToast.showShortBottom('Something Went Wrong').then(function(success){}, function(err){});
    console.log(err.message);
  });

  //Get other religions
  $scope.otherReligions = [];
  var query = "SELECT religions.name FROM religions WHERE religions.name != ?"
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [$scope.currentReligion]).then(function(res){
   if (res.rows.length > 0) {
      for (var i=0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
        $scope.otherReligions.push(res.rows.item(i));
        // $scope.currentReligion = res.rows.item(0);
      }
    }
  }, function(err){
    $cordovaToast.showShortBottom('Something Went Wrong').then(function(success){}, function(err){});
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```